# Confusion about argument result

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

As part of a larger problem, I wish to find the arguments $\theta$ for the complex numbers $-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. This is $\theta = \arctan(-\sqrt{3})$, which is $-60^{\circ}=300^{\circ}$ for the positive and $\theta = \arctan(\sqrt{3})=60^{\circ}$ for the negative.

However, it is then given in a solution to the problem that the possible arguments are only $120^{\circ}$ and $240^{\circ}$. I feel as though I am missing something painfully obvious, but I don't understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct formula is
$$\tan(\theta) = \frac{y}{x},$$
where $x$ and $y$ are the real and imaginary parts, respectively of a complex number $z$, and $\theta$ is its argument. However, students tend to make the following incorrect simplification:
$$\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right).$$
The above is wrong, as $\tan^{-1}$ can only produce angles between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, i.e. complex numbers in the first or fourth quadrants, i.e. complex numbers with positive real components.

Try plotting the number. You'll see immediately that its argument is definitely not $-\pi/3$. Use the fact that $\tan$ has period $\pi$, and you'll see that instead the answer is $-\pi/3 + \pi = 2\pi/3$, or $120^\circ$; this angle produces the same $\tan$ value, and lies in the correct quadrant.

Comment: Without plotting it, how do we discern what $\theta$ is? In other words, how do we know that $-60^{\circ}$ is not possible without plotting?

Comment: I always encourage plotting, but you can discern it by looking at the sign of $x$. If it's positive, then the $\tan^{-1}$ formula applies. If it's negative, then add/subtract $\pi$, to get one of the arguments. If you want the principle argument, depending on whether you define this to be in $(-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ or $[0, 2\pi)$, you may need to also pay attention to the sign of $y$.

Comment: If the sign of $x$ is negative and the sign of $y$ is positive, isn't that the same thing as the entire expression being negative?

Comment: Certainly, if $x$ is negative and $y$ is positive, then $\frac{y}{x}$ is negative. However, if $\frac{y}{x}$ is negative, then either $x < 0$ and $y > 0$, or $x > 0$ and $y < 0$, so I wouldn't call it "the same thing". That's part of the problem is that $\tan^{-1}$, when fed in a negative number $\frac{y}{x}$, whether $x > 0$ and $y < 0$ or $x < 0$ and $y > 0$, and by convention, assumes the former is true. So, when you have the latter is true, you need to add/subtract $\pi$ radians.

Answer (score 1):

first u need to find x=arc tan|y/x| then if the point is in first qudrant result should be same. if quadrant 2 result should be pi- x . if 3rd answer should be -(pi-x) if 4th answer should be -x
here the points lie in 2nd and 3 rd respectively . so answer would be (pi-60) and -(pi-x)
ie 120 and -120 but -120 is equivalent to 240 (360-120)